# Make sure method is called on all declared and inherited members of some type

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, composition

I want to apologize for the title, but I didn't know how to summarise this problem.

---

I've got the following class called `AbstractWriter`:

```
public class AbstractWriter {

    private boolean changePerformed = false;

    // Some Setters

    private void changePerformed() {
        if (!changePerformed)
            changePerformed = true;
    }

    public boolean isChangePerformed() {
        return changePerformed;
    }

    protected <S> void setValue(
        Class<S> type, Object oldValue, Object newValue, Setter setter) {
        // Do something
        changePerformed();
    }
}
```

Whenever a setter is called, the method `setValue(…)` is invoked. All setter implement this rule.

Then there's `AgeWriter`, extended from `AbstractWriter`:

```
public class AgeWriter extends AbstractWriter {
    // Some Setters
}
```

And then again, there's `HumanWriter`:

```
public class HumanWriter {

    // Some setter calls are delegated to this Writer
    private AgeWriter ageWriter = new AgeWriter();

    // Some Setters

}
```

When I now invoke the method `isChangePerformed()` on `HumanWriter`, I only know if a setter on `HumanWriter` has been called, but not if one of those delegate setters to `AgeWriter`.

I'm now looking for a general way to solve this problem. Here are some ways I tried respectively thought about:

- Try to find all members of type `AbstractWriter` with Reflection. But `getDeclardFields` misses out on inherited ones and `getFields` on `private` ones.
- Make `isChangePerformed()` `abstract` so that every implementation has to make sure it's implemented correct.
- Create the `abstract` method `getAbstractWriters` that returns all `AbstractWriter`s used inside this type.

What would be your ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: You might be better off with a `Map` rather than some bizarre reflection apparatus.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the `ageWriter` private to `HumanWriter`, there is no way any external object calls a setter on `AgeWriter` directly. Use encapsulation, by not providing any accessor to the ageWriter, and use methods on `HumanWriter` that delegate to the `ageWriter`.

You could also use an observable/observer pattern (JavaBeans property change listeners) and add the HumanWriter as a listener to the AgeWriter. This way, every property change on the ageWriter will trigger an event that will be sent to the HumanWriter.

Comment: I've revised my question, since I've forgotten something. All setters call the common method `setValue(…)`. This makes the first paragraph of your answer no longer applicable.

Comment: I don't see how it makes it no longer applicable.

Answer (score 0):

My idea may be stupid. But I thing it should work:). You can use the list of writers...

```
public abstract class AbstractWriter {

    private List<AbstractWriter> writers;

    //...

    private boolean changePerformed = false;

    //...


    public boolean isChangePerformed() {
        for (AbstractWriter writer : writers) {
            if(writer.isChangePerformed() && changePerformed) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```